# How does one take the end result of a loop as an int for further use?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have written a basic loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = a; i > 0; i = i - 7)
    {
        if (i < 7)
        {
            printf("%i", i);
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to print the end result, but I want to extract the result as an `int` so I can use it for calculations later on, how would I go about that?

Comment: Define `i` outside of the loop.

Comment: You are asking about general methods/constructs when using loops, aren't you? Then see comment above and answer below. I ask because the result for that specific loop is available as `int i = a%7;`.

Comment: Hi @dbush, I attempted to implement your advice, but I think I have done it incorrectly, because I'm now getting unexpected results when I run the program. I put my new code in the edit- what mistake did I make? Edit: Figured it out, thanks!

Comment: I undid your latest edit, which changed the question to the point of invalidating the answer you got. Generally please do not edit solutions into the question. You can however add details on the problem you had here, to allow better answer, not however so that the existing ones are not applicable anymore. If the insights here cause you to have another question please ask it as a separate new question.

Comment: @Yunnosch, okay, understood.

Comment: Oops, it seems I rolled back to the wrong version, but your last edits solved/hid that mistake I made. Thanks for that and for understanding what I tried to tell you and achieve. ;-) Luckily I did not confuse you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare `i` in the loop initializer, it'll be scoped to the for loop. So, declare it before the `for` loop, then assign it in the initializer:

```c
int i;
for (i = a; i > 0; i = i - 7) {
    // ...
}
printf("%i\n", i);
```

Comment: Hi Aplet, when I do this I get the error "declaration shadows a local variable". I have included my new code in my edit above, have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You still have "int i" in two places.